# How do I keep two cards and hide one with show more button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see I have three cards and could have multiple more. How do I hide certain cards by default and show them by clicking on the "View more" button? For example, in this case, I want to hide the last card and show it by clicking on "View more".

Can someone please help? This would be much appreciated

Regards,
Bill

```js
$(".card-border").on("click", function() {
  // Toggle the div background color
  $(this).toggleClass("card-bg");
  // Find the button
  var btn = $(this).find(".btn");
  // Toggle classes for ONE button
  btn.toggleClass('btn-add-item btn-rmv-item');
  // Depending on a button's class, change it's text
  (btn.hasClass("btn-rmv-item")) ? btn.text("Remove"): btn.text("Add this extra");
});
```

```css
.card-border {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-bg {
  background-color: rgba(89, 211, 137, .08);
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}

.upsell-pricing {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.upsell-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}

div.ho-border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fuel Replacement -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Fuel replacement</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£49/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price include upto a full tank of petrol/gas.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Portable WiFi Hotspot -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Portable WiFi hotspot</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£10/day</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Get the luxury of portable WiFi hotspot on the go. The price include unlimited data usage for the day.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a class to the boxes that you need to hide, and using jQuery you can set .show() on button click

Comment: Do you want the button to be inside *each* card, and open the contents of the card? Or do you want the button to show completely new cards?

Comment: @Carsten's solution is great IMO. If you need something simpler however, simply wrap your hidden cards in a div that has these classes : `hidden-cards hidden` (where hidden is set to `display: none`) and on button click do : `$(".btn-view-more").on("click", function() {
 $(".hidden-cards").toggleClass("hidden");
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very simple like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var visEle = $(".card-border:visible");
  var hidEle = $(".card-border:not(:visible)");

  if (hidEle.length > 0) {
    $('.card-border:last').after('<button class="showMore">Show more</button>')
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".showMore", function() {
    hidEle.first().show();
    hidEle = $(".card-border:not(:visible)");
    if (hidEle.length == 0) {
      $(".showMore").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

And in your CSS I've added:

```
.card-border:not(:nth-child(-n+3)) { // this show the first 2 elements
  display: none;
}
```

This will allow you to automatic show a `showMore` button if there are any hidden `.card-border`

```js
$(".card-border").on("click", function() {
  // Toggle the div background color
  $(this).toggleClass("card-bg");
  // Find the button
  var btn = $(this).find(".btn");
  // Toggle classes for ONE button
  btn.toggleClass('btn-add-item btn-rmv-item');
  // Depending on a button's class, change it's text
  (btn.hasClass("btn-rmv-item")) ? btn.text("Remove"): btn.text("Add this extra");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var visEle = $(".card-border:visible");
  var hidEle = $(".card-border:not(:visible)");

  if (hidEle.length > 0) {
    $('.card-border:last').after('<button class="showMore">Show more</button>')
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".showMore", function() {
    hidEle.first().show();
    hidEle = $(".card-border:not(:visible)");
    if (hidEle.length == 0) {
      $(".showMore").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card-border {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-border:not(:nth-child(-n+3)) {
  display: none;
}

.card-bg {
  background-color: rgba(89, 211, 137, .08);
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}

.upsell-pricing {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.upsell-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}

div.ho-border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fuel Replacement -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Fuel replacement</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£49/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price include upto a full tank of petrol/gas.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Portable WiFi Hotspot -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Portable WiFi hotspot</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£10/day</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Get the luxury of portable WiFi hotspot on the go. The price include unlimited data usage for the day.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**Show all on click**

```js
$(".card-border").on("click", function() {
  // Toggle the div background color
  $(this).toggleClass("card-bg");
  // Find the button
  var btn = $(this).find(".btn");
  // Toggle classes for ONE button
  btn.toggleClass('btn-add-item btn-rmv-item');
  // Depending on a button's class, change it's text
  (btn.hasClass("btn-rmv-item")) ? btn.text("Remove"): btn.text("Add this extra");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var visEle = $(".card-border:visible");
  var hidEle = $(".card-border:not(:visible)");

  if (hidEle.length > 0) {
    $('.card-border:last').after('<button class="showMore">Show more</button>')
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".showMore", function() {
    hidEle.show();
    $(".showMore").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.card-border {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-border:not(:nth-child(-n+3)) {
  display: none;
}

.card-bg {
  background-color: rgba(89, 211, 137, .08);
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}

.upsell-pricing {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.upsell-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}

div.ho-border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fuel Replacement -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Fuel replacement</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£49/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price include upto a full tank of petrol/gas.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Portable WiFi Hotspot -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Portable WiFi hotspot</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£10/day</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Get the luxury of portable WiFi hotspot on the go. The price include unlimited data usage for the day.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**View less button**

```js
$(".card-border").on("click", function() {
  // Toggle the div background color
  $(this).toggleClass("card-bg");
  // Find the button
  var btn = $(this).find(".btn");
  // Toggle classes for ONE button
  btn.toggleClass('btn-add-item btn-rmv-item');
  // Depending on a button's class, change it's text
  (btn.hasClass("btn-rmv-item")) ? btn.text("Remove"): btn.text("Add this extra");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var visEle = $(".card-border:visible");
  var hidEle = $(".card-border:not(:visible)");

  if (hidEle.length > 0) {
    $('.card-border:last').after('<button class="showMore">Show more</button>')
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".showMore", function() {
    hidEle.show();
    $(".showMore").hide();
    $('.card-border:last').after('<button class="showLess">Show less</button>')
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".showLess", function() {
    $(".card-border").not(visEle).hide();
    $(this).remove();
    $(".showMore").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.card-border {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-border:not(:nth-child(-n+3)) {
  display: none;
}

.card-bg {
  background-color: rgba(89, 211, 137, .08);
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}

.upsell-pricing {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.upsell-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}

div.ho-border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fuel Replacement -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Fuel replacement</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£49/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price include upto a full tank of petrol/gas.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Portable WiFi Hotspot -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Portable WiFi hotspot</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£10/day</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Get the luxury of portable WiFi hotspot on the go. The price include unlimited data usage for the day.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great all around solution.

Comment: Appreciate the kind words @Jake

Comment: Thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen for this great solution. But I have a question, for example, tomorrow I have 5 cards, and I want to show 2 by default and hide all three. This code ain't going to help. Because what it does is it's hiding the last card only. So I have will have 4 cards displaying in one hidden. What if you do something like. By default show 2 cards and rest of all the cards are hidden and visible on show more button?

Comment: @BillNathan if you look at the css `.card-border:not(:nth-child(-n+3))` this will show the 2 first elements only, look at the demo.

Comment: Yes, this works! But the last tweak would be. That if you notice the first two elements is shown by default. Then if we click on ShowMore it only reveals one more element, if we need more we need to keep clicking show more. How about showing 2 elements by default and then show any hidden elements all together? Instead of clicking show more again and again?

Comment: @BillNathan Look at the second demo i've added, just belove `Show all on click`

Comment: Can we have a final button for "view less". So it goes back to default view which is 2 elements show and rest hidden?

Comment: @BillNathan I've updated it, if you need more you need to open a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191259/discussion-between-billnathan-and-carsten-lovbo-andersen).

Answer (score 1):

Add  class 'hideclass' to all the cards you want to hide .Hope this helps.thanks

```js
$('.hideclass').hide() //To hide extra contents

$(".card-border").on("click", function() {
  // Toggle the div background color
  $(this).toggleClass("card-bg");
  // Find the button
  var btn = $(this).find(".btn");
  // Toggle classes for ONE button
  btn.toggleClass('btn-add-item btn-rmv-item');
  // Depending on a button's class, change it's text
  (btn.hasClass("btn-rmv-item")) ? btn.text("Remove"): btn.text("Add this extra");
});

$(".show").on("click", function() {
 
  $(this).hide()
  $('.hideclass').show()
 

});
```

```css
.card-border {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-bg {
  background-color: rgba(89, 211, 137, .08);
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}

.upsell-pricing {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.upsell-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}

div.ho-border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fuel Replacement -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Fuel replacement</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£49/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price include upto a full tank of petrol/gas.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Portable WiFi Hotspot -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Portable WiFi hotspot</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£10/day</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Get the luxury of portable WiFi hotspot on the go. The price include unlimited data usage for the day.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!-- Post-trip Cleaning -->
<div class="card-border ho-border hideclass">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip cleaning</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>


<div class="card-border ho-border hideclass">
  <h4 class="float-left">Post-trip test</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£30/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Return the vehicle without bothering about post-trip cleaning. This extra does not cover damages to the vehicle seat, stains, spills, and smoke burns.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<button class="show">Show More</button>
```